# NDSolve with external function

Tags: differential-equations

I have a complicated function `g[a_,s_,t_]` where `s_`and `t_` are constants added by hand for now. I would like to solve equations like

```
NDSolve[{f''[a] + (4/a + D[g[a,s0,t0],a]/g[a,s0,t0])*f'[a] + 
f[a]*m/(g[a,s0,t0]^2*a^2) == 0, f[astart] == 1.5, f'[astart] == 0}, f,
{a, astart, aend}]
```

but the term with the derivative of `g[]` does not evaluate properly -- without it everything works fine. I tried different things with `Evaluate[]`and `D[g[x,s0,t0],x]/.x->a`but nothing seems to work. What is the correct syntax for including the derivative of an external function?

Comment: Your code works for me.  It must be your definition of `g`.  (Other perhaps the other undefined things.)

Comment: Perhaps you can use `Derivative[1,0,0][g][a,s0,t]`